# Parse CSV file using Apache Camel and log count of successful and failure rows

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-ftp

I have a requirement to parse a CSV file which can contain 100 to 10000 rows. Inorder to do this I am using the below route configuration.

```
from(inputFileUri)
        .routeId(CUSTOm_ROUTEID).delayer(1000)
        .split(body().tokenize("\n", 100, true))
        .unmarshal(new BindyCsvDataFormat(CustomObject.class))
            .convertBodyTo(List.class)
        .process(customProcessor);
```

I am able to do the needful. But I want to log how many rows were successfully parsed and how many had errors and log error rows separately and maybe write them to a new csv file once after the input csv file is processed.
Is there a camel way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write your error rows to a new CSV file and not get in the way of processing your good batches, you probably want to look into a DeadLetterChannel (`DLC`).

But my guess is if 1 out of your 100 rows has an issue, then then entire 100 rows you're splitting on are never going to make it to your processor.

I feel like you are better off splitting on your new line without the `100`, then aggregate after your `unmarshal`.  Rows that fail to unmarshal can be handled by a `DLC` and rows that successfully get converted to a `CustomObject` can be grouped up with an aggregator and sent to your `customProcessor` as a `List<CustomObject>`.

You don't even need to write your own AggregationStrategy - you can use `GroupedBodyAggregationStrategy`

It would probably look something like this

```
from(inputFileUri)
  .routeId(CUSTOm_ROUTEID).delayer(1000)
  .errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("direct:input-file-dlc"))
  .split(body().tokenize("\n"))
    .unmarshal(new BindyCsvDataFormat(CustomObject.class))
    .aggregate(constant(true), 
            new GroupedBodyAggregationStrategy())
         .completionSize(100)
         .completionPredicate(
            exchangeProperty(SPLIT_COMPLETE).isEqualTo(TRUE))
      .process(customProcessor)
    .end() // End Aggregation
  .end(); // End Split
```

Comment: I would write a unit test that passes in a multi-line string with rows of data that you know are bad and assert which messages are sent to the dead letter channel and also assert what messages are sent to the processor at the end